# How to divide one list by another?

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, data

I have two lists which I generated from two plots.

```
list1 = Cases[
Cases[InputForm[plot1], Line[___], 
Infinity], {_?NumericQ, _?NumericQ}, Infinity];

list2 = Cases[
Cases[InputForm[plot2], Line[___], 
Infinity], {_?NumericQ, _?NumericQ}, Infinity];
```

Now I want to divide the `list1` by `list2` and then plot this resulting `list3` vs. `x`. Can anyone please help me with this?

Comment: Please format the post an place all code in a code block.  Make sure that the code can be copied back into Mathematica intact. Click edit above, then if you need help click the ? button in the editing toolbar.

Comment: If the lists are of equal length, then the division operator `/` works as expected.

Comment: Just a comment: list division only makes sense if both lists are on the same x-grid.

Comment: Yes, they are on the same grid.

Answer (score 5):

The problem here is that list1 and list2 will not be on the same gridding (i.e. at the same x positions}. So the general approach is to convert the lists into interpolation functions and divide the two.

```
plot1 = Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 10}];
plot2 = Plot[x, {x, 0, 10}];
list1 = Cases[
   Cases[InputForm[plot1], Line[_], 
   Infinity], {_?NumericQ, _?NumericQ}, Infinity]; 
list2 = Cases[ 
   Cases[InputForm[plot2], Line[_], 
   Infinity], {_?NumericQ, _?NumericQ}, Infinity];
```

Unequal lengths:

```
Length[list1] == Length[list2]
<* Out[] = False *>

inter1 = Interpolation[list1];
inter2 = Interpolation[list2];
Plot[inter1[x]/inter2[x], {x, 0, 10}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot Markus! Interpolation solved my problem! The problem was that the lists were not of same size and that's why simple divide function "/" was not working.